# Delete row before insert a new one

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How can I achieve to Delete a row before Insert a new one in the same Table. I tried it with a Trigger but I read that it is not possible because it could cause a deadlock.

I also wanted to save the row which should be deleted to another table (example Table B) before delete it and then Insert a new one (into Table A).

Is there any other ways to do it ?

PS: They will have the same key

Comment: Well the simple answer would be to write a query to read the row, then write it to another table, then delete the row, then insert a row with new data

Comment: Or, if they have the same key, why are you deleting/inserting, instead of updating?

Comment: If they have the same key, why not simply updating the row?

Comment: you can do this by using a sp and apply query appropiately

Answer (score 0):

You could use `UPDATE`...

```
UPDATE tbl
SET col1 = newCol1,
    col2 = newCol2
WHERE etc = etc
```

And If you want to insert updated row to another table you could use `TRIGGER AFTER UPDATE` for that.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TriggerName ON Tbl
AFTER UPDATE
AS
INSERT INTO Log (Col1, Col2) 
SELECT Col1, Col2
FROM deleted
```

Comment: What if the Row not exists ? With this solution I only can do it when its already in my Table

Comment: @AhmetKazaman In this case you could use `if exists (select ....) begin /*query to update*/ end else begin /*query to insert*/ end`

Comment: You mean like this ? "DELIMITER //
IF EXISTS (SELECT ... WHERE ID=...) 
BEGIN
UPDATE ...;
END//
ELSE
BEGIN
INSERT ...
END //
DELIMITER ;" Because thats not working for me :"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'BEGIN" . What Im doing wrong ? And will this effect the peformance of my query ?

Comment: Does it even work in mysql ?